# how to mark file has already read using java

Tags: java, msg

i'm scanning a folder for msg files. after reading it a ihave mark that file as read. i'm using apache POI package to read msg file.
how to do it in java

Comment: I think it is better if you keep a list of files that you already read and check whether the file that you gonna read already exist in that list

Comment: thanks @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne i'll do it in the same manner or i'll move read files to other folder..

Comment: Or rename it to a different extension that you aren't processing.